# Listen to enter key press on a text box

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to see an alert text when one press enter key in a text box.
In jquery i can check each key up event and if it is 13 key code i can do an alert.

Is this a place i can use knock out easyly?

how can i trigger a function on pressing enter key in a  input type text

Comment: is it not a place to use knockout?

Comment: It sounds like you figured it out. What's the question? Show what code you have and explain why it doesn't work like you want it to.

Comment: Your title says "triggering". Your description says "listening". Which one is true?

Comment: Event binding in knockout is described here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

Answer (score 8):

Sure you can.  Use the [`event`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) binding to add a handler for the `keypress` event and do what you want.  The second parameter on your handler is the event object.  When you detected that enter was pressed, you can do whatever you want.

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="value: message, event: { 'keypress': keypress }"/>
```

```js
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.message = ko.observable(data.message);

    var KBD_ENTER = 13;
    self.keypress = function (data, event) {
        if (event.which == KBD_ENTER) {
            alert('hey! you pressed enter.');
        }

        // let the event propagate (if you want)
        return true;
    };
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/8fB4t/)

Answer (score 7):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#div").bind("keypress", function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
        // TRIGGER YOUR FUNCTION
    }
});
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. He doesn't want to trigger the event. He wants to trigger his own function when the event happens.

Comment: Still misunderstood. He wants to listen through Knockout.js